# Wait for service when calling function in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a Javascript beginner and trying to understand promises and asynchrony but it has been hard.

I have this function in my service:

`main.service.js

```
function getTableauUrl() {

  $http.get(TABLEAU_URLS).then(function (response) {
      var urls = response.data;
      getUser().then(function (data) {
        var company =  data.account.name;
        for (var i=0; i< response.data.length; i++){
          if (urls[i].name === company){
            return urls[i].url;
          }
        }

      }, function errorGetUser(error) {
        $log.info(error);
      });
    }
  );
}
```

This function works fine if I use it immediately, but if I call it from a controller:

```
function  MainController ($log, $rootScope,  $scope, $sce, $q, $state,
                            mainService) {

var url = mainService.getTableauUrl();

  }
```

Then the variable url is undefined. I know it is because of the asynchronic behavior of Javascript but tried modifying it to add a promise but I read some tutorials and I didn't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning anything from that method. Try returning the `$http.get`

```
function getTableauUrl() {
  return $http.get(TABLEAU_URLS).then(...);
}
```

then calling it in your controller like below:

```
function  MainController ($log, $rootScope,  $scope, $sce, $q, $state, mainService) {    
    var globalUrl;

    mainService.getTableauUrl().then(function(url) {
        globalUrl = url;
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried what you said, but it's still returning undefined.